# How to mutate properties of a structure in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm new to swift. I have a structure called Class that represents a class a student would take, I have a method called updateTotalGrade that updates the total grade based on the grade of the assignments. What I'm noticing is that I can't change the value of totalGrade after I've set it initially.

This is the code from a function my structure classCreate that creates and returns a class, I set the total grade to .72 and then use my method to update it.

```
var cl = Class(id: UUID(), className: "Physics 109: Physics in the Arts (002)", totalGrade: 0.72, categories: categories)
cl.updateTotalGrade()
```

This is the Class structure and the updateTotalGrade method. Basically the issue is that it doesn't change totalGrade ever, totalGrade is always .72

```
struct Class: Equatable, Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    // Class name
    @State var className:String
    // Total grade
    @State var totalGrade:Double
    // List of categories
    @State var categories = [Category]()
    
    static func == (class1: Class, class2: Class) -> Bool{
        return class1.className == class2.className
    }
    
    func updateTotalGrade(){
        // In case a category is empty, increase the relative weight of other categories
        var totalWeight = 0.0
        for category in categories{
            if (!category.assignments.isEmpty){
                totalWeight += category.categoryWeight
            }
        }
        
        totalGrade = 0.0
        for category in categories{
            totalGrade += category.getGrade() * (category.categoryWeight/totalWeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: `mutating func ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using `SwiftUI`, don't set properties as `@State`. Instead, mark `updateTotalGrade()` function as `mutating`:

```
var totalGrade: Double // @State removed
...
mutating func updateTotalGrade() {
...
```